# Autoload do composer não está funcionando

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer, xampp, autoload

Boa noite(ou qualquer turno caso vc seja do futuro).

Bem, o meu problema é objetivo, porém, até agora sem solução.

Desenvolvi um projeto todo no meu PC windows usando XAMPP.

Como o sistema tem várias classes eu estou usando autoload do composer da seguinte maneira:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
            "persistencia\\": "libs/persistencia/",
            "sistema\\": "libs/sistema/"
    }
}
```

Estrutura de pastas:

```
libs
├── persistencia
│   ├── categoriaproduto.php
│   ├── cliente.php
│   ├── contrato.php
│   ├── funcionario.php
│   ├── itemcontrato.php
│   ├── mensageiro.php
│   ├── modelodados.php
│   ├── persistenciaexception.php
│   ├── persistencia.php
│   ├── produto.php
│   ├── relatorio.php
│   └── tipoacesso.php
└── sistema
    ├── logger.php
    ├── sistemaexception.php
    └── sistema.php
```

Rodando o sistema no XAMPP aqui no meu Win estava tudo ok. O problema ocorre quando eu preparei um servidor ubuntu, apache, mysql, php7.2.

Instalei o composer, transferi os arquivos do meu site executei o "composer install" e o resultado foi:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'sistema\Sistema' not found in
>   /var/www/html/api.php:18

O código em questão é esse:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

require_once('../config.php');

if(Config::REQUISITAR_LOGIN) // Se for nescesário estar logado para usar o sistema
   testarLogin(); //Impedindo acesso de usuários não logados
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(Config::CORS) //Checando se deve ou não habilitar Cross Origin
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if(!Config::EXIBIR_ERROS) {// Impedindo ou não a exibição de erros
   error_reporting(0);
   ini_set('display_errors', 0);
}

use sistema\Sistema;

try {
  $sistema = new Sistema; /*ESSA É A LINHA 18 QUE DEVIA FUNCIONAR*/
} catch(Exception $e) {

echo '{"status": "falha", "erro": "'.$e->getMessage().'"}';

exit(0); // A API não pode funcionar sem o sistema
}
```

O problema não deve estar em como eu escrevi o composer, pois estava funcionando até trocar a plataforma.

Em fim, não encontrei respostas que pudessem me ajudar, então obrigado a quem se voluntariar.

Comment: O arquivo da classe `Sistema` parece ser `sistema`, o que é errado para o Composer. O arquivo deve possuir o mesmo nome da classe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o sistema de arquivos do Windows é *case incentive* e no Ubuntu é *case sentitive*.

O que isso quer dizer? No Windows `use Sistema\Sistema` funciona com arquivos todos em maiúsculo como em minúsculo (`libs/sistema/sistema.php`, `libs/sistema/Sistema.php`, `libs/Sistema/sistema.php`, `libs/SiStEmA/SiStEmA.php`).

Já no Linux o seu use tem que ser exatamente igual, `use Sistema\Sistema` só irá carregar o arquivo `libs/Sistema/Sistema.php`

Para resolver isso, independente do sistema, adote *camel case* para tudo:

```
"psr-4": {
        "Persistencia\\": "libs/Persistencia/",
        "Sistema\\": "libs/Sistema/"
}
```

A mesma ideia nos nomes dos arquivos e pastas.

Comment: Fiz o que você disse e tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.